# Datadog unit of time for monitor time aggregation

Tags: alert, monitoring, datadog

I've been trying to understand the time aggregation for Datadog monitoring alerts. The official doc http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/monitors/#define-the-conditions
I understand the idea of time aggregation, but I'm confused about the unit of time as it's not mentioned anywhere. Is it aggregating over 1 minute intervals? 
To rephrase this when I use `sum(last_30m){X}` is it summing the values of `X` for each minute? What about `sum(last_1h){X}`? Is it still each minute?

Answer (score 0):

Datadog monitors evaluate every minute, I think. So in your `sum(last_30m){X}` example, every minute, the monitor would sum the values of `{X}` over the last 30 minutes, and if that value was above whatever threshold you set, then it would trigger an alert. Same thing for `sum(last_1h){X}`, but every minute it would evaluate the sum over the last 1 hour.